# creating a LWC component - form

Tags: lightning-web-components, form

I am self-taught backend java developer (wannabe). I didnt do much in frontend. Could someone explain to me how to make LWC component with 6 fields form? It's like in a simple HTML page? Or you have to do something more than that? I am using Intelij Ideam Ultimate. I need form + java backend. Ive installed salesforce cli and sfdx in VSC. Is there any generator which would create it for me?

Comment: Are you planning to store data in Salesforce or somewhere else.

Comment: In sql database

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a good understanding of HTML and different concepts in Javascript(latest standards). If you want to store data in Salesforce, you need to have a good understanding of Apex code, Objects creation in Salesforce, etc.

A good way to learn this is through trailhead. LWC specific trail can be accessed here - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components
This will give idea about how LWC components are built.

If you want to try handson LWC, you may check this out - https://webcomponents.dev/

There is also a paid tool avonni - https://www.avonni.app/features/lightning-components-builder which you may check out, if you want drag and drop capability for building lwc components.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question correctly, then for creating the UI based forms you can have to rely on the html part where you decide the look and feel of the form, how the UI will look. Apart from that you need to write the java script part to decide what happens when someone fills data in those fields or maybe click a button. In VSC when you try to create a lightning component you will see automatically .html, .js and .xml file is created. If you have a requirement to take action on the database then you can separately create an aura class to query and perform other DML operation. In fact to focus more on the UI you can create a .css file too.

You may also consider looking into the Salesforce documentation or maybe this this trail(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/journeytosalesforce/trailmixes/all-about-lwc) too for your understanding.